# How do I keep top-most navigation node in the menu?

Tags: navigation, navbars

I have just created a new Enterprise Wiki site.
In the left hand menu I've got a number of pages, and those pages have a number of sub pages.

I am wondering, how can I keep the top-most node so that it doesn't disappear?

For example...

Top Menu:

[image]

Clicking on Client Records:

[image]

Clicking on Carers and Recipients:

[image]

How do I navigate back up the tree from Carers and Recipients? Is there a way to keep the parent menu link?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on Publishing Infrastructure feature (if its not already activated).. than you can manage Navigation by going to Site Settings -> Under Look and Feel -> Navigation

Here you can manage Left Navigation by adding new nodes or deleting existing ones.. My doubt is that you just need to make sure your subsites inherit Left Navigation from its parent site (root-site) and you should manage all the links within the root-site by yourself (i.e. deleting existing pages or adding sub-nodes for subsite links

Answer (score -1):

Site Settings------>look and feel(Navigation)----->   Display the same navigation items as the parent site